# React show element if input has value and hide if empty

Tags: reactjs

im trying to show the p element when the input filed has value "the user writes something in input field" and hides when the input is empty

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function textInput() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onKeyUp={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
      
      {
        isOpen ?
                <p>result</p>
            : null
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default textInput
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write code like below. It works.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function textInput() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("")

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={ (e) => {
        setInputText(e.target.value)
      }
      }/>
      { (inputText !== "") && <p>result: {inputText}</p> }
    </>
  )
}

export default textInput;
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using an `isOpen` prop, consider maintaining the text in state. Then, if the text is not empty, show the `<p>` component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function textInput() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {text && <p>result</p>}
    </>
  );
}

export default textInput;
```